# Cannot search date (Month Word)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a search text box I and then a button that i use for searching records.

I am able to search by IDs and status. But I want to search for date too by using the text box

Is that Possible?

ASPNET

```
<div class="pull-right col-lg-11">
    <center>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="form-control" bordercolor="Black"></asp:TextBox>
  </center>
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" class="btn btn"
            BackColor="CornflowerBlue" Style="color: White"
            OnClick="btnSearch_Click">
         <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is what i have tried at my code behind.

C# Codes:
FOR BUTTON CLICKED

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            GetPR();
        }
        else
        {
            GetPRSearch(txtSearch.Text);
        }
    }
```

MY GET

```
void GetPR()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Receiving.ReceivingID, Receiving.POID, Receiving.FinalDeliveryDate, " +
            "Receiving.Status, Receiving.DateReceived, Receiving.ReceivedByID, Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, PO.CompanyName FROM Receiving " +
            "INNER JOIN Users ON Receiving.ReceivedByID=Users.UserID INNER JOIN PO ON Receiving.POID=PO.POID ORDER BY Receiving.DateReceived DESC";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Receiving");
        lvPurchases.DataSource = ds;
        lvPurchases.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }

void GetPRSearch(string keyword)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Receiving.ReceivingID, Receiving.POID, Receiving.FinalDeliveryDate, " +
            "Receiving.Status, Receiving.DateReceived, Receiving.ReceivedByID, Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, PO.CompanyName FROM Receiving " +
            "INNER JOIN Users ON Receiving.ReceivedByID=Users.UserID INNER JOIN PO ON Receiving.POID=PO.POID " +
            "WHERE Receiving.ReceivingID LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR PO.CompanyName LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Receiving.POID LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' " +
            "OR Receiving.DateReceived LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Receiving");
        lvPurchases.DataSource = ds;
        lvPurchases.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

By using this i **can't** search for just "April" 
Thank you guys in advance! Advises are very much appreciated.

Comment: JSON's answer is the way to go but you have an issue here in your code in that it's wide open to an SQL Injection attack within `GetPRSearch`. You need to parameterise your inputs.  Better still you should move the query into a Stored Procedure which will have the added benefit of making future changes/maintenance much easier.

Comment: will you be so kind to give us the database engine you are using? i'm sure where is an easier way to search by using the built in functions on the engine.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER @thepanch

Comment: read my answer below, it works trust me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thinking in the case you are using sql server you can simply do this.

```
"Select * from yourtable WHERE Datename(month,YOURDATEColumn) like '%'+ keyword + '%'"
```

That way the built in function will retrieve the month name in the current language.

Here you can find more information about this https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174395%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: It does not view me any record which the date is april :(

Comment: try this use this simple select and see what you are getting `SELECT Receiving.ReceivingID, Receiving.POID, Receiving.FinalDeliveryDate, " +
            "Receiving.Status, Receiving.DateReceived, Receiving.ReceivedByID, Datename(month,DateReceived) as ReceivedMonth FROM Receiving` and see the months name you are getting

Comment: Okay done. I'm just calling the wrong table name. Thank you so much! I USED the one you told before `"Select * from yourtable WHERE Datename(month,YOURDATEColumn) like '%'+ keyword + '%'"`

Comment: Good it helped, any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you values in your database are stored as a datetime SQL will automatically convert a string to a datetime.  So you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE tablename.date = '04/01/2016'
```

If you wanted to choose values for the entire month you would need to select the range:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE tablename.date >= '04/01/2016'
AND tablename.date <= '04/30/2016'
```

If your values are stored as a string
you will need to convert the values to a datetime in order for the range to work.  Do so like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE convert(datetime, tablename.date, 101) >= '04/01/2016'
AND convert(datetime, tablename.date, 101) <= '04/30/2016'
```

If you are letting users only select an entire month and not just a single day, I would use a dropdownlist instead of a textbox.

Comment: Will try this now. Thank you very much for considering. i'll let you know what's the result!

Comment: Maybe i should just try doing dropdown list

Comment: @pauline-gail-mallari-chan: Using a drop down list would restrict the user from using only using values you set.  Then you don't have to do any input validation or worry about SQL injection for this value.